Holomorphic Function and its Analytic Continuation and solving contour integral
While studying for my Complex Analysis course, I came across the following question:

In this problem, $a_1, a_2$ are real numbers with $ a_1 < a_2 < 0 $. We define
$$
\Omega = \mathbb{C} \setminus (-\infty, a_2].
$$
(a) Prove that there exists a holomorphic function $ f $ on $ \Omega$ such that $ f(0) > 0 $ and
$$
f(z)^2 = (z - a_1)(z - a_2) \quad \text{for } z \in \Omega.
$$
(b) Show that the function $ f $ from part (a) can be analytically continued to $ \mathbb{C} \setminus [a_1, a_2] $.
(c) Compute the integral
$$
\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\gamma} \frac{dz}{zf(z)},
$$
where $ \gamma $ is a simple closed curve in {$z \in \mathbb{C} \mid \operatorname{Re}(z) < 0$ } $ \setminus [a_1, a_2]$
that winds around the interval $[a_1, a_2]$ once in the counterclockwise direction.

I think I managed to prove part (a):
Look at the function $g(z) = (z-a_1)(z-a_2)$. We can see that $g(0) = a_1 . a_2 > 0$.
Notice that $g(z)$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}$, so it is also holomorphic on $\Omega$.
Because $g$ is a nowhere vanishing holomorphic function in a simply connected region $\Omega$, there exists a holomorphic function $g$ on $\Omega$ such that
$$
g(z) = e^{h(z)}
$$
This is Theorem 6.2 in chapter 3 of 'Complex Analysis' by Stein & Shakarchi.
Now take $f(z) = e^{\frac{h(z)}{2}}$. We can see that $f$ is holomorphic and $f^2 = e^{h(z)} = g(z)$ with $f(0) = e^{\frac{h(0)}{2}} > 0$. This proves part (a) I believe.
However, I have no idea how to solve part (b) or (c). Can someone help me with this please?
Thanks in advance

For part b, try to show that $f$ is continuous up to the line $(-\infty, a_1)$ and then apply Morera's theorem. Maybe argument principle helps.
